# What do ほかには and ほかのは mean?

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, particle-は, particle-の

What do ほかには and ほかのは mean? How are they different from one another?

And why is に used in ほかに? Is there an explanation for it or is it just naturally said? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ほかには means "Other than that..." where "that" refers to the topic you were discussing. に here is working adverbially, as it would in expressions like 一般的に.

ほかのは means "As for the other one(s)..." To my ear, の is working as a pronoun as it would be in 私のは e.g.:

> このカバンは重いですが、他のは軽いです。

This briefcase is heavy; the other ones are light.

Comment: ほかには is for questions and ほかのは is general statement? Is this right?

Comment: @ccccc Nope.. ほかに(は) is an adverbial phrase "other than that, ..." and ほかの(は) is a noun phrase "the other ones"